# How to introduce a delay between webrequests to a site in C#?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, delayed-execution

I am making multiple requests to a website. How can I introduce a delay between requests to slow down my process? Is there a method that allows me to just cause the thread to wait for X seconds before proceeding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx)?

Note that it causes the *current* thread to sleep - you don't target it at a *different* thread. But if you've got a loop within one thread, making multiple requests, you could easily add it in to the loop to restrict your request rate.

The `Sleep` method is overloaded - one signature takes a `TimeSpan` and the other takes a number of milliseconds. Personally I'd generally prefer the first one, as it leaves no room for ambiguity. For example:

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

is obviously asking the thread to sleep for 2 seconds - not 2 minutes, 2 milliseconds etc.

Comment: +1 For mentioning feeding `Sleep` a `TimeSpan`.  That's a good idea that I'd never really thought about.

Comment: Thread.Sleep may not work because "If there are no other threads of equal priority that are ready to run, execution of the current thread is not suspended." - msdn doc

Comment: @anphu: That's in the context of "If the value of the millisecondsTimeout argument is zero, the thread relinquishes the remainder of its time slice to any thread of equal priority that is ready to run." If you call `Thread.Sleep` with an actual positive (and non-negligible) amount of time to sleep, it *doesn't* just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
```

…where `x` is the number of milliseconds to sleep the thread.

An alternative is to use a `Timer` and do a request each time the `Tick` event fires.